# How to update a field on the sum of the joined values?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have three tables. Table market contains all the items and their prices. Table users contains a list of all users and their balance. Table bought contains lists id's of sold items and id's of buyers. I need to subtract the prices, which users spent on the items. When I make this query

```
`UPDATE market m
JOIN bought b ON m.id=b.id AND m.status="need"
JOIN users u ON u.id=b.buyer
SET m.status="sold", m.date=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, u.balance = u.balance - m.price`
```

balance updated only on the first-line market value. How i can subtract all prices?

//===========

users

id balance

1  100

//===========

market

id price

1 1

2 2

3 3

//===========

bought

id  buyer

1  1

3  1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query:

```
UPDATE market m JOIN
       bought b
       ON m.id = b.id AND m.status = 'need' JOIN
       users u
       ON u.id=b.buyer
    SET m.status = 'returned',
        m.date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        u.balance = u.balance - m.price;
```

When multiple rows match, then one is arbitrarily chosen for the update.  The updates do not accumulate.  You can get what you want, but you need two updates, one with an aggregation:

```
UPDATE users u JOIN
       (select b.buyer, sum(price) as sumprice
        from market m JOIN
             bought b
             ON m.id = b.id AND m.status = 'need'
       ) mb
       ON u.id = b.buyer
    SET u.balance = u.balance - m.price;

UPDATE market m JOIN
       bought b
       ON m.id = b.id AND m.status = 'need'
    SET m.status = 'returned',
        m.date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```